# Problemas em carregar imagens no Latex (Overleaf)

Tags: imagem, latex

Estou com problemas em carregar imagens no Latex (Overleaf). No momento em que insiro a mesma no documento, aparece escrito o endereço dela no local onde ela está disponível.

Tentativas realizadas:

1 - Criação dos caminhos `\usepackage{graphicx}` e `usepackage\graphicspath{ {img/} }`
2 - Conversão da extensão do arquivo para jpeg.

Segue prints para uma melhor exemplificação

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s49VJ.png)

O comando utilizado para a inserção da figura está dessa maneira:

```latex
\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{img/page_1_Cronograma.jpg}
    \caption[Rótulo da Figura, descrevendo a figura]{Rótulo da Figura, descrevendo a figura \cite{icse2015}.}
    \label{fig:figura1}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.